# Can not find WAR file path after deployment using tomcat 8 manager

Tags: java, tomcat

I have been testing my tomcat 8 setup on debian 9. Everything seems fine until I try to deploy a helloServlet WAR file through tomcat 8 manager. I created the very simple example program following the instruction [here](https://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaServlets.html).

I use tomcat manager to upload the HellowServlet.war from my working directory. Then I can access it though http://localhost:8080/HelloServlet/sayhello

The program works just fine. However, no matter how I search (/etc/tomecat8  /usr/share/tomcat*), I just can not find the war file or any components inside of it. I really want to know the exact location of my application file. Anyone may tell me where the application files are stored by the tomcat 8 mananger?

More update:

I just tried to upload the same war file again, and I got following message from tomcat

```
FAIL - War file "HelloServlet.war" already exists on server
```

That means the war file is sitting somewhere on the server, but the path is unknown to me.

Comment: Did you check `tomcat/webapps` folder? It must be having a folder named `HelloServlet`.

Comment: I don't have that folder. Tomcat 8 seems to be different form 7 (I don't have experience on 7 though). My folder is like this: /etc/tomcat8/Catalina/localhost under that there are bunch of xml files. My server.xml has "name=localhost  appBase=webapps  unpackWARs=true"

Comment: What's the value of env variable `$CATALINA_BASE`?

Comment: $CATALINA_BASE is not defined. I find it in my /etc/tomcat8/web.xml  But it's inside comments. Not being defined.

Comment: "env | grep CATALINA" returns nothing...

Answer (score 0):

Found it.... it's inside /var/lib/tomcat8/webapps

However, I can not find any configuration file in tomcat 8 describing that it uses /var/lib/tomcat8 as one of its working directory.